# Sharepoint 2010 API upload a file with metadata creating a new version from ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, web-services, api, sharepoint, document

How I can upload a file with metadata creating a new version from ASP.NET web application to SharePoint 2010?

Is there any way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "without creating new vesion"? You can always upload documents using Client API or Server API.

Comment: As i mentioned earlier you can use Client Object Model. For example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/03/12/uploading-files-using-client-object-model-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to upload a file to a document library.

Perhaps the simplest way is simply to copy the file to the document library's URL using File.Copy. SharePoint supports WebDAV so you can treat a library as a network folder, opening/saving files directly from any application, copying and renaming from Windows Explorer etc.

You do face some limitations though:

- The full path of the file can't be larger than 260 characters and SharePoint will truncate it without warning.
- The file name can't contain some characters that are valid for Windows Explorer, eg `#`
- If you try to save a file with the same name as an existing one, SharePoint will create a new file with a slightly different name without asking
- You have no control over the `author` and `creation date` properties. SharePoint will use the current date and the credentials of the user executing the code.
- You can't set any metadata although you can update the file's ListItem properties after uploading.

Another option is to use the Client object model and upload the file using [File.SaveBinaryDirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/LIBRary/ee538285.aspx). This option is better than simply copying the file, as it allows you to overwrite an existing file, but you still don't get direct access to the file's properties. Uploading could be as simple as this:

```
var clientContext = new ClientContext("http://intranet.contoso.com");
    using (var fileStream =new FileStream("NewDocument.docx", FileMode.Open))
        ClientOM.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext,
            "/Shared Documents/NewDocument.docx", fileStream, true);
```

Another option is to connect to a library using the Client Object Model and then create a file using [FileCollection.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/LIBRary/microsoft.sharepoint.client.filecollection.add.aspx), eg

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = documentsList.RootFolder.Files.Add(
fileCreationInformation);
```

Check this SO question, [Upload a document to a SharePoint list from Client Side Object Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847935/upload-a-document-to-a-sharepoint-list-from-client-side-object-model) on how to use both SaveBinaryDirect and [FileCollection.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/LIBRary/microsoft.sharepoint.client.filecollection.add.aspx). The answers display both how to upload a file and how to modify its properties