# Is there any way to fill in Sharepoint entries via parsing text file?

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, sharepoint

My workplace has a whole bunch of unannotated .zip files that need to be uploaded to the new file server (Windows). I've used perl to parse through through the excel files within the .zip files to create an annotation.txt file for each .zip file that contains information about the .zip file. I have 1000's of zip files and do not want to manually enter in information for each entry if there's a way to automate it. I am proficient in perl and mysql, and wondering if there is any way to utilize my skillsets to port this information into the Microsoft Sharepoint website.

Thank you in advance for any advice or suggestions.

Comment: There does appear to be code on CPAN which interfaces with Sharepoint; you might be able to adapt it for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There a many, many ways to meet your requirement.

You could write a event receiver to parse the files once uploaded and set metadata.
A better approach for your use case might be to write a .NET based console application and reference Microsoft.SharePoint.Client and then upload your files using the Client side object model (CSOM) and set the metadata during that process as outlined here: [Upload a document to a SharePoint list from Client Side Object Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847935/upload-a-document-to-a-sharepoint-list-from-client-side-object-model)

There are also REST and ASMX webservices that you could call from a non .NET runtime process.

Plenty of options, pick the one that fits your needs and skills best.