# Upload file to the SharePoint site with Azure App credentials

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-core-sdk, pnp-framework

I have

- Registered Azure Application
- that have full control permissions to the SharePoint site

and these variables

- SharePoint Site Url
- TenantId
- ClientId
- ClientSecret

I need to upload a document to the SharePoint Site Folder.

I tried to use [PnP Core SDK](https://pnp.github.io/pnpcore/) but I am not able to configure the Authentication, it seems that there is no [authentication provider](https://pnp.github.io/pnpcore/api/PnP.Core.Auth.html) to just accept plain password (`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider` does not accept name of the application as a username).

Overall the `PnP Core SDK` is adding a lot of complexity to my console application because it depends on `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host`.

is there a way how to authenticate via PnP or should I use REST API directly?

Alternatively the [PnP Framework](https://github.com/pnp/pnpframework/blob/dev/docs/MigratingFromPnPSitesCore.md#delegated-authentication) that will be deprecated (if I understand the documentation correctly) can authenticate towards Azure Application, but this is only documentation I found.

Any idea or recommendation?

### Update

When I try this (PnP Framework)

```cs
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using PnP.Core.Model.SharePoint;
using PnP.Framework;

ClientContext context =
                new AuthenticationManager()
                    .GetACSAppOnlyContext(
                        siteUrl: "siteUrl",
                        appId: "clientId",
                        appSecret: "password");
    
IFolder? folder = (IFolder?)context.Web.Folders.Where(f => f.Name == directory).FirstOrDefault();

if (folder == null) throw new Exception("Folder not found.");

folder.Files.Add(filename, content, overwrite);
```

I am getting this exception

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CollectionNotInitializedException: 'The
> collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the
> request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly
> requested.'

Any Idea how to explicitly request the collection?

Comment: I am currently doing some research on this issue, will let you know as soon as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create ClientContext

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using PnP.Framework;

ClientContext _context =
                new AuthenticationManager()
                    .GetACSAppOnlyContext(
                        siteUrl: siteUrl,
                        appId: appId,
                        appSecret: appSecret);
```

Method for uploading the file

```
public void UploadFile(Stream stream, string listTitle, string directory, string filename, bool overwrite)
{
      List list = _context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
      var url = Path.Combine(directory, filename);
      var file = new FileCreationInformation() { ContentStream = stream, Overwrite = overwrite, Url = url };
      var addedFile = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(file);
      _context.Load(addedFile);
      _context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Call example

```
UploadFile(stream, "Documents", "Shared Documents/FooSubFolder/", "filename.txt", true)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to my research and testing, if you want to connect to SharePoint Online with Azure App credentials, you can use the following code, and then upload file to SharePoint:

```
string siteUrl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/demo";
using (var cc = new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, "[Your Client ID]", "[Your Client Secret]"))
{
    cc.Load(cc.Web, p => p.Title);
    cc.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(cc.Web.Title);
};
```

Here is a document about upload file to SharePoint, you can refer to the code in this document: [Upload a document to a SharePoint list from Client Side Object Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847935/upload-a-document-to-a-sharepoint-list-from-client-side-object-model)

Also, you can try to install `Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM` to fix the error:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CollectionNotInitializedException: 'The
> collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the
> request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly
> requested.'

More information for reference: [Granting access using SharePoint App-Only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs)

Comment: Thank you, installing `Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM` did not help to fix the exception. I will try to rewrite the code.